# How can I change shipping amount before execute payment using PayPal restAPI

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, express-checkout

I try to migrate our old express checkout process based on PayPal classic API to new RestAPI , but a question has arisen during the new process:

How can I change shipping amount after create a payment and just before execute payment using PayPal restAPI?

Request after create payment:

```html
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "AUD",
        "total": "100",
        "details": {
          "shipping": "10",
          "subtotal": "75",
          "tax": "15"
        }
      },
      "description": "Transaction description.",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "quantity": "5",
            "name": "Item Name",
            "price": "15",
            "currency": "AUD",
            "sku": "sku"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://localhost:56508/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx?guid=77096",
    "cancel_url": "http://localhost:56508/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx?guid=77096"
  }
}
```

request before execute payment:

```html
{
  "id": "PAY-12X5617352981972MKQ64KKA",
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "AUD",
        "total": "101",
        "details": {
          "shipping": "11",
          "subtotal": "75",
          "tax": "15"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

PayPal response back after execute payment:

```html
{
  "id": "PAY-12X5617352981972MKQ64KKA",
  "create_time": "2014-10-15T00:51:52Z",
  "update_time": "2014-10-15T00:52:43Z",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
      --------------------
-----------------------------
----------------------
      }
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "AUD",
        "total": "100.00",
        "details": {
          "shipping": "10.00",
          "subtotal": "75.00",
          "tax": "15.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "Transaction description.",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "quantity": "5",
            "name": "Item Name",
            "price": "15.00",
            "currency": "AUD",
            "sku": "sku"
          }
        ],
        "shipping_address": {
         ------------------------------
        }
      },
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "5KX17441UU9021742",
            "create_time": "2014-10-15T00:51:52Z",
            "update_time": "2014-10-15T00:52:43Z",
            "amount": {
              "currency": "AUD",
              "total": "100.00"
            },
            "state": "completed",
            "parent_payment": "PAY-12X5617352981972MKQ64KKA",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5KX17441UU9021742",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5KX17441UU9021742/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-12X5617352981972MKQ64KKA",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "state": "approved",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-12X5617352981972MKQ64KKA",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the shipping amount after creating a payment . You need to pass shipping amount in the execute payment call and it will override the shipping that you set while creating the payment .

Request passed in while creating the payment :

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://www.fff.com",
    "cancel_url": "http://www.fff.com"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "20.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "18.00",
          "tax": "1.00",
          "shipping": "1.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is payment description.",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "quantity": "3",
            "name": "Hat",
            "price": "2.00",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "description": "This is desc",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          {
            "quantity": "3",
            "name": "Hat",
            "price": "2.00",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "description": "This is desc",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          {
            "quantity": "3",
            "name": "Hat",
            "price": "2.00",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "description": "This is desc",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

While executing the payment :

**https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2NX408505D489885FKQ6M7NA/execute/**

```
{
  "payer_id": "KQMQZ9Y7XZYBA",
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "28.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "18.00",
          "tax": "5.00",
          "shipping": "5.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is payment description.",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "quantity": "3",
            "name": "Hat",
            "price": "2.00",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "description": "This is desc",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          {
            "quantity": "3",
            "name": "Hat",
            "price": "2.00",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "description": "This is desc",
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          {
            "quantity": "3",
            "name": "Hat",
            "price": "2.00",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "description": "This is desc",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Response :**

```
{
  "id": "PAY-2NX408505DYT5005FKQ6M7NA",
  "create_time": "2014-10-14T07:24:36Z",
  "update_time": "2014-10-14T07:29:09Z",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
      "email": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "first_name": "Eshan Personal Test",
      "last_name": "Account",
      "payer_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "shipping_address": {
        "line1": "cxas",
        "line2": "asa",
        "city": "FL",
        "state": "FL",
        "postal_code": "95616",
        "country_code": "US",
        "recipient_name": "Eshan Personal Test Account"
      }
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "28.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "18.00",
          "tax": "5.00",
          "shipping": "5.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is payment description.",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "Hat",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "price": "2.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": "3",
            "description": "This is desc"
          },
          {
            "name": "Hat",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "price": "2.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": "3",
            "description": "This is desc"
          },
          {
            "name": "Hat",
            "sku": "product12345",
            "price": "2.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": "3",
            "description": "This is desc"
          }
        ],
        "shipping_address": {
          "recipient_name": "Eshan Personal Test Account",
          "line1": "cxas",
          "line2": "asa",
          "city": "FL",
          "state": "FL",
          "postal_code": "95616",
          "country_code": "US"
        }
      },
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "04B04851PF2563348",
            "create_time": "2014-10-14T07:24:36Z",
            "update_time": "2014-10-14T07:29:09Z",
            "amount": {
              "total": "28.00",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
            "state": "completed",
            "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
            "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
            "parent_payment": "PAY-2NX408505D485005FKQ6M7NA",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/04B04851PF2563348",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/04B04851PF2563348/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2NX408505D485005FKQ6M7NA",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-2NX408505D485005FKQ6M7NA",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see , I have passed the new shipping amount while executing the payment and it will be final one .

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is what I thought in a first step  but when I pass new shipping through execute method PayPal response back with approved state and the old shipping which is means the amount is not overridden
did you check PayPal response after do execute as well

Comment: Yes i checked it and it was the one i set in execute api.

Comment: Not sure  i will paste my response with shipping amount. And can you post yur request for both api?

Comment: I have pasted my response and you can see my new shipping rates were applied . The only difference I see in your execute request is that you haven't passed the item_list object as I did in my request . Can you try to pass the item_list object also in execute payment ?

Comment: I tried with item_list and also all the other parameter but still same response without new shipping applied it is really weird..

Comment: the problem was that I forgot to adding new transactions with new amount into the PaymentExecutation transactions argument.

Comment: Yeah! long time ago, I forgot mark this thread as an answer,Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like REST supports the Express Checkout [Callback API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/), which is used to update shipping and tax totals within Express Checkout. It's not surprising since REST is aimed at mobile developers and they wouldn't necessarily want the extra bandwidth spent.

Comment: No one wants extra bandwidth spent but still everyone needs mechanism to modify even in mobile environment like me