# Paypal express checkout rest sales tax

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I am using PayPal Express checkout (REST API, and server-side integration)
I understand the current workflow as:

1. Add button on page (using their javascript)
2. When the paypal button is clicked, the js calls my webservice that gets an OAuth token, and initiates the checkout, returning a payment id.
3. The Javascript then calls paypal to display the UI, and returns a payer id
4. My checkout page then executes the payment and shows a confirmation page.

My current issue is that I don't know the customer's state for tax calculation at this point, or zipcode for shipping options.

Is there a way I can, after getting the OAuth token but before creating the payment, get the user's preferred shipping and billing address, 
OR
Is there a method i can use to update the payment information with tax and shipping costs after creating the payment but before executing the payment?

I do know that using the REST API for Express checkout, they don't calculate taxes or shipping, and the instant update doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question has already been answered at the link below. The instructions are exactly the same for your situation except you would change the tax amount instead of the shipping amount.

[How can I change shipping amount before execute payment using PayPal restAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350802/how-can-i-change-shipping-amount-before-execute-payment-using-paypal-restapi)